# What is 'Invalid (Error Code: 4)'?

Tags: import

Trying to import a small set of contacts with relationships, I got this error: `Invalid (Error Code: 4)`. We have checked all fields and couldn't identify any thing special.

Any idea? BTW is there a list of error codes?

An example of the set of data: [import file](https://cloud.all-in-group.fr/index.php/s/WzkH5exL2rNj3mR)

Comment: It may help for us to see a sample of your spreadsheet (columns, cells).

Comment: I've edited my post with a link to the file

Comment: it seems to be a regression in 5.50.X